# ROC curves using MultiClass Random Forest: native MultiClass approach or OnevsRest?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, multiclass-classification

For a multiclass problem, I can use sklearn's [RandomForestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) out of the box:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = load_iris(as_frame=True)

y = data['target']
X = data['data']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)

RF = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
RF.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_score = RF.predict_proba(X_test)  # shape is (30, 3)
```

Or I can replace the above

```
RF = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
RF.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_score = RF.predict_proba(X_test)  # shape is (30, 3)
```

with this to train 3 binary-classification models:

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
RF = OneVsRestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42))
RF.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_score = RF.predict_proba(X_test)  # shape is (30, 3)
```

I can then go on and binarize the output and use `y_score` to plot ROC curves as per the [official docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html).

I am unsure which approach to take: the standard RandomForest multiclass approach, or the OneVsRest approach? For some models like SupportVectorClassifiers, one must use OvO or OvR for multiclass. However, RandomForest is different since the multiclass approach is native to the algorithm.

What makes me lean towards OvR in this case is that in the [official docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html) is written:

> ROC curves are typically used in binary classification to study the output of a classifier

and OvR is binary classification...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info